# SVN export yields different file permissions on 2 systems with same umask

Tags: ubuntu, svn, file-permissions, export, umask

I have a machine with Ubuntu 10.10 and a machine with Ubuntu 11.10.

When I do a svn export on the 10.10 machine, this gives all directories a 755 permission. The 11.10 machine sets the directories to 775. The umask is the same for both systems (0022). The permissions of the parent directory (in which we do the SVN export) is set to 755 on both systems.

How can I control the permissions for SVN export?